# Combo box not visible with xtype:combo. there is no form involved

Tags: extjs

Team,

I am facing one problem where combo box is not rendering on the div. My apology  if it is very basic but I am newbie to EXTJS.

Ext Js version is 3.x. Even I donot know how to format the code so apology on that as well.

code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Expansion</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/ext-all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="c1"></div>

<div id="c2"></div>

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

Ext.onReady(function(){
var itemsl=[];
itemsl.push([Ext.apply({
xtype:'combo',
triggerAction: 'all',
mode: 'local',
store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
id: 0,
fields: [
'myId',
'displayText'
],
data: [[1, 'item1'], [2, 'item2']]
}),
valueField: 'myId',
displayField: 'displayText',
emptyText: 'deactivated listbox',
_isExpanded: true,
isExpanded : function(){
return this._isExpanded || (this.list && this.list.isVisible());
},
renderTo: Ext.get('c1')
})

]);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a misunderstanding of how Extjs works by the asker.  xtype:"combo" will only work if your configuration is a child element of another extjs component.  In the case of your example, you are not putting your combo in another extjs component, so there is nothing to call it's configuration to actually initiate it with an xtype.  Note that Ext.apply is not a component, just a function that moves properties into an object.

Answer (score -1):

please use renderTo config in the Ext.apply();